# I need to convert some code so that it does not contain the 'auto' keyword

Tags: c++

I have created a program but in the code I used 'auto' and have found out that im not allowed to. I can not figure out how to not use it as ive always just used it. Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Here is the code i have:

```
string reverse_word(string str)
{
    string output_str;

    output_str.reserve(str.length());

    char save_non_alpha = 0;

    for (auto it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); it++) {

        if (it == str.rbegin() && !is_letter(*it)) {
            save_non_alpha = *it;
        }
        else {
            output_str += *it;
        }
    }
    if (save_non_alpha != 0) {
        output_str += save_non_alpha;
    }
    return output_str;
}
```

Comment: why you are not allowed to use it? `auto` can be replaced by using `decltype`, though it makes the code less readable and I am not sure if that would be in the spirit of your actual constraints

Comment: Add the flag: -std=c++17 to your compile command

Comment: You can always replace `auto` with the exact type.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Almost. You can't do that with lambda expressions : `auto x = [](){};`. In that case `auto` can't be replaced with the explicit type of the lamdba. The best you can do is wrap it in something else, like an `std::function`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If he's not allowed to use `auto`, what are the chances he's allowed to use lambda expressions?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True. Lambdas are special.

Comment: @FredLarson OP probably won't be using a lambda here, but it's still an exception to the rule that you can always replace `auto` with the explicit type.

Comment: @user463035818, my lecturer just said for now she doesn't want us to use auto for some reason

Comment: Ok. My suggestion to use decltype wasnt that serious. If you have constraints like that you better include them in the question. It helps to give appropriate answers

Answer (score 4):

You should use the right returned type by the str.rbeghin() to replace the auto so i guess this should be enough

```
for (std::string::reverse_iterator it=str.rbegin(); it!=str.rend(); ++it)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, as you haven't explained why you ain't able to use it, I'm gonna assume it rejects your program.

For a long time, Gcc was defaulting to c++98. If you are still using it, try changing the default standard. This can be done with the flag -std=.
Some possible values include: c++11 (official standard that introduced it), c++0x (pre-release implementation of c++11), c++14, c++17, c++2a

In case you use a different compiler, like Clang, you can use the same flag. MSVC uses /std=, and the only supported values are c++14, c++17 and c++-latest.

If your compiler is too old to support any of these, I recommend upgrading your compiler.